# Extend React Native Component with native Code

Tags: javascript, java, android, ios, react-native

I am interested in extending a `Component`, provided by `react-native` with some native code. The closes example I can find is [react-native-maps](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps). It feels like they are extending the [MapView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.31/docs/mapview.html) component (since the `Components` from `airbnb` and `facebook` have the same *name*) – but I am only guessing here.

So, lets say I would want to extend the  component with these peaces of code ([android](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapUrlTile.java), [iOS.h](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/ios/AirMaps/AIRMapUrlTile.h)/[iOS.m](https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps/blob/master/lib/ios/AirMaps/AIRMapUrlTile.m)) and expose something like this on the frontside in `react-native`:

```
<MapView.UrlTile
    urlTemplate={someURL}
    />
</MapView>
```

How would I go on about it? For every hint I am grateful.

Comment: Really interesting question! Hopefully someone can answer it?